# mysql return rows where link table matches two sets of conditions

Tags: mysql

I need to search an order database for orders which include a combination of items from different manufacturers. Essentially I need a list of any orders with 2 or more items, where one item is from manufacturer A and one item is from manufacturer B.
I figure I can use a 'like' on the sku column since they are prefixed with two letters representing the manufacturer. The relevant tables and columns for sake of examples are as follows:

orders table has an order_id and a create_date (unix timestamp - I need orders in the past two years - I can handle this part but include it in case anyone feels generous)

order_items table includes a column for the relevant order_id and an order_item_id. It also includes a product_sku. sku's would look like MA-?????? for manufacturer A and MB-????? for manufacturer B.

I'm not an sql expert and have a feeling it involves selects in selects with count() functions involved, but not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just realized, to get the id's themselves, the order table is irrelevant. I can manipulate what I need once I can retrieve a list of matching order_ids - so I guess the question is specific to the items table.

Answer (score 0):

actually found an answer quicker than I thought I would:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM orders AS o
WHERE
 o.order_id IN (select  DISTINCT order_id FROM order_items WHERE order_item_sku LIKE 'MA-%')
 AND
 o.order_id IN (select  DISTINCT order_id FROM order_items WHERE order_item_sku LIKE 'MB-%')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understend what you want, I would select order_item_id from table orders, and group and count, or only order by etc:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_item_id), product_sku
    FROM order
    GROUP BY product_sku;
```

If you want to see all order_item_id for every product_sku togather:

```
SELECT order_item_id, product_sku
    FROM order
    ORDER BY product_sku ASC;
```

Comment: the goal was to list any orders and all the items related to such orders when the items included two or more items where one started with one vendor's prefix and at least one other started with the other vendor's prefix. I found an answer using 'IN' to compare against another select shortly after posting (I didn't  think I would find anything that fast because I didn't know what I was looking for).